# Inheritance for Angular Router Providers

Tags: angular, angular-router

I was recently trying to refactor some code a bit and ran into a issue I do not understand. I have a shared module that exports a spinner:

```
@NgModule({
...snip...
exports: [ ...snip..., Spinner, ....snip....]
}
export class SharedModule { }
```

I then import this module into others. I ran into an issue when moving to child routes

Other Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { Component} from './component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        OtherRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [Component]
})
export class OtherModule { }
```

Routing Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Component} from './component';
import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Component,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'one',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'one',
                component: OneComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [
        OneComponent
    ]
})
export class OtherRoutingModule { }
```

My issue is this: If I try to use the Spinner component (`<spinner></spinner>`) within `Component` it will work, however if I try and use it within `OneComponent` I get an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'spinner' is not a known element

```
Component <- using spinner here works
OneComponent <- Using spinner here causes error
```

If I declare all the components in the Module, and not the Routing Module, it works, its not until I move to declare the child components from the Routing module that I get the issue. From this I assume it has something to do with the inheritance, but I don't understand why - I am sure I could work around it by importing the `SharedModule` in the Routing Module as well, but that seems overkill when the routing module is an extension of the module (`OtherModule`)

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjckdu

Link to example. In the example, if you add `<app-spinner></app-spinner>` to the component `OtherOne` (app/other/other-one/other-one.component.html) it will fail, however it works when declared in the component Other (`OtherComponent`)

Apologies about the naming convention, I should have chosen other words....

Comment: Why don't you just import `SharedModule` in the global `modules.ts`? This way you have it in one place and available in all components.

Comment: can you create a demo of the problem on stackblitz?

Comment: That's normal and expected. OneComponent belongs to OtherRoutingModule, which doesn't import SharedModule. So the directives, pipes and components of SharedModules aren't usable inside OneComponent. Either move OneComponent to the OtherModule, or import SharedModule in OtherRoutingModule. A routing module typically doesn't declare components.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that, that its only visible within the context of the Module. Reason for declaring it that way round is so that there is no need to import the components in the module, only to declare them when they are only referenced or used from within the routing module. Seemed a bit like double handing, importing the components in both places